# Explicitly calculate shape operator for graph of $f(x,y)=xy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This seems trivial but I am stuck. To gain intuition for a bigger problem, I am trying to compute the shape operator of the graph of $f(x,y)=xy$ at the point $p=(0,0,0)$, call this surface $\Sigma$. In class we defined the shape operator at $p\in \Sigma$, in terms of the covariant derivative.

$$S(\vec v) = -\nabla_{\vec v}N=-\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}N(p+t\vec v).$$
where $\vec v\in T_p\Sigma$ and $N$ is normal to $\Sigma$.

Let $F(x,y,z)=xy-z$. I know $N = \frac{\nabla F}{|\nabla F|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}(y,x,-1)$. Say $\vec e_1,\vec e_2$ are basis vectors for $\Sigma$. I know I need to find $S(\vec e_1)$ and $S(\vec e_2)$, from there I can find the matrix of $S$. This is where I am stuck, if someone can show how to do the calculation, that would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the shape operator from the Weingarten equations, that is from the first and second fundamental form? I reckon it is much easier to work on the point $p=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: What is $F(x,y,z)$? I can not seem to understand why you defined it if you are looking for the shape operator of the hyperbolic paraboloid.

Comment: The problem is, neither the first nor fundamental form were presented in class. $F$ as in here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The surface is naturally parameterized by $(x, y)$:
$$(x, y)\mapsto (x, y, xy)$$
So there are natural tangent vectors
$$e_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=(1, 0, y)$$ $$e_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}=(0, 1, x)$$
Hence (using your notation and let $r=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$)
$$\begin{align*}
  S(e_1) &=-\frac{d}{dt} N(p+te_1)\\
         &= -\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\\
         &= -(-xy, 1+y^2, x)/r^3\\
  S(e_2) &=-\frac{d}{dt} N(p+te_2)\\
         &= -\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}\\
         &= -(1+x^2, -xy, y)/r^3
\end{align*}$$
Evaluating at $x=y=0$ we get
$$S(e_1)|_{(0, 0)}=-(0, 1, 0)=-e_2, S(e_2)_{(0, 0)}=-(1, 0, 0)=-e_1$$
Hence the matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 &-1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I understand. My problem was I was stuck on $e_1,e_2$, I was lacking understanding of coordinate patches, but I spent the last day reading up